# UIBarButtonItem background image and setting action

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I created button in navigation bar with this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButtonEn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"EN" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(buttonEN:)];
```

My action for this button:

```
- (void) buttonEN:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"English language"); 
}
```

This works fine but I have to change background and button's style (code below).

```
UIImage *imageEN = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cys_lang_en.png"];
UIButton *buttonImgEN = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonImgEN.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, imageEN.size.width, imageEN.size.height );
[buttonImgEN setImage:imageEN forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *myButtonEn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonImgEN];
```

This is axactly what I need, but I need to set action

```
[myButtonEn setTarget:self];
[myButtonEn setAction:@selector(buttonEN:)];
```

This code is compiled with no errors but button does not respond.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: set target and action for UIButton(buttonImgEN) not UIBarButtonItem

Comment: If I add code:
[buttonImgEN setTarget:self];
[buttonImgEN setAction:@selector(buttonEN:)];
I receive an error: "Not visible @interface for UIButton declares the section setTarget"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 40.0f)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEN:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cys_lang_en.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *eng_btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = eng_btn;
}

-(void)buttonEN:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"English language");     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are Missing `action` and `target` for button

You can set using,

```
[myButtonEn setTarget:self];
[myButtonEn setAction:@selector(buttonEN:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change apperance of this button.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:<doneBackgroundImage>
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use custom view for image, 
Try to use:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:@selector(selector)];
```